# Наследование классов, переопределение

Tags: java, c#, ооп

> Делаю потиху задания из решебника и это на третьем пункте меня выбило
> немного из колеи.
>
> Создать объект класса Котёнок, используя классы Животное, Кошка.
> Методы:
>
> 1. вывести на консоль имя,
> 2. подать голос,
> 3. рожать потомство (создавать себе подобных).

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Cat cat = new Cat();
            Kitten kitten = cat.giveBirth();
            System.out.println(kitten);
            cat.printName();
        }
    }
     

interface Mother {
    <T extends Animal> Kitten giveBirth();
}
 
 
abstract class Animal {
    protected String name;
    abstract void say();
    public void printName() {
        System.out.printf("My name is %s\n", name);
    }
}
 
class Cat extends Animal implements Mother {
    public Cat() {
        name = "Cat";
    }
 
    @Override
    public <T extends Animal> Kitten giveBirth() {
        return new Kitten();
    }
    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.printf("Meow\n");
    }
}
 
class Kitten extends Animal {
    public Kitten() {
        name = "Kitten";
    }
 
    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.printf("Meow\n");
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы это работало с вывода в main, то есть как-то так:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat("nameCat");
        cat.say(); 
        System.out.printf(cat.giveBirth());
 
        Cat catTwo = new Cat("nameCatTwo");
        catTwo.say(); 
        System.out.printf(catTwo.giveBirth());
    }
}
```

И правильно ли я понял третий пункт? Что он должен выводить? Почти 6 утра, не понимаю уже ничего. И как корректно переопределить для каждого класса методы `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `toString()`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас класс `Kitten`, как минимум, неправильно реализован. Вообще, он в целом и не нужен, так как котёнок - это таже кошка, только маленькая.

Но если уж хотите отдельный класс под котёнка, то наследовать его надо от `Cat`, а не `Animal`.

Реализация кошки тоже странная: `class Cat extends Animal implements Mother`. Кот не мать, он не может рожать. Или же тут имелась ввиду кошка именно как самка?

Плюс, вы реализуете этот интерфейс у кошки, а не у базового класса `Animal`. В таком случае, к примеру, если вы захотите создать класс для собаки `Dog`, то там тоже будете этот интерфейс реализовывать? По-хорошему, такие вещи нужно как можно выше в иерархии классов реализовывать.